# Copy pictures from Ubuntu Phone to desktop computer

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I cannot transfer pictures from my Ubuntu Phone to my Ubuntu-desktop. When I browse files on my phone, they all have type .sci

AMT

Answer (score 0):

The file extension should not influence whether you can copy or not.

`.sci` [seems to be](http://filext.com/file-extension/SCI) an obscure graphics file format. Try installing [XNViewMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xnviewmp/) and browsing the files with that.